# Как узнать текущие свойств блока (например цвет фона, внутренний и внешний отступ)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Четвертый час бьюсь над этой задачей только ошибки выдает. Уже все справочники перечитал, просто завис на одном месте.
Мне в 3 alerta их вывести только и все.
Если можно покажите на моем блоке.

```css
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ring">
</div>
```

Comment: А суть вопроса то в чем? Стили блока вы ж привели...

Comment: Мне в 3 alerta их вывести только и все.

Comment: ниже ответ дал с алертами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему вы ищете функцию [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

но [jQuery.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) уже вызывает ее внутри себя.

```js
console.log('jQuery.css: ', $('.ring').css('box-shadow'));
console.log('window.getComputedStyle: ', window.getComputedStyle($('.ring')[0]).getPropertyValue('box-shadow'));
```

```css
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ring">
</div>
```

Comment: getComputedStyle про него читал, но так и не смог на своем примере, мне первой строки вашего ответа будет достаточно. Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Если суть вопроса в том как  с помощью `jQuery` узнать, то `$('.ring').css('padding');` например, выдаст вам внутренний отступ заданный блоку

```
alert($('.ring').css('padding')); // внутренний отступ 
alert($('.ring').css('margin')); // внешний отступ
alert($('.ring').css('background')); // фон
```